# Merge or reword the "set-phrases" and "expression" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

I wrote the tag wiki for the [set-phrases](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-phrases) tag, which is used 11 times and reads:

> Phrases with fixed words used as a single unit, many of which are idioms.

We also have a [expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) tag which I personally found a bit vague so I didn't tackle its tag wiki. Now that it has been written it reads:

> A set phrase used commonly in the Japanese language

So does this mean the latter tag is in fact vague, or is it functionally a synonym for the former? Or do we just need to reword one or both of them to clear up how they really differ?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that [expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) is a good tag because it is too vague to mean anything.  Expressions can be anything written or spoken, and they can be words, phrases, sentences, paragraphs or the entire text.  I would like to discourage its use, and instead encourage to use more specific tags such as [phrase](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) or [sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence) (the latter is currently not in use).

Comment: I can imagine [tag:phrase] and [tag:sentence] being useful, but I can also imagine them being vague too. I wonder if we can think of some example or model type questions for each that [tag:set-phrase] and [tag:idiom] would not be suitable for.

Comment: @hippietrail: How about [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/477/looking-for-expressions-similar-to-or-for-situations-that-are-opposite) and [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/926/grammatically-correct-expression-similar-to-the-slang)?  なるほど, やっぱり and って感じ are words or phrases, but calling them set phrases or idioms is stretch at best.