# Do we need all three tags "set-phrases", "expression" and "idioms"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Apparently [this has been discussed already 4 years ago](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/merge-or-reword-the-set-phrases-and-expression-tags). We have three tags

- [idioms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)
  Questions about those **phrases with fixed words** used as a single unit, which typically have a meaning beyond what is...
- [expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression)
  A **set phrase** used commonly in the Japanese language
- [set-phrases](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-phrases)
  **Phrases with fixed words** used as a single unit, many of which are idioms.

  (emphasis mine)

I think we should make [expression](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) a synonym of [set-phrases](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-phrases) (or the other way around), but I think for tags about set phrases, expressions, idioms, we have at least one too many.

(For inspiration, the difference between the words "phrase, expression, idiom" has been [asked over on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/difference-between-phrase-idiom-and-expression).)